# ProgressBar on TForm2 of C++ Builder

Tags: progress-bar, c++builder

On the `TForm2`, I'm trying to make a `TProgressBar` that starts at 0%, and takes 30 seconds to get to 100%. The `TProgressBar` will begin to go up as soon as `TCheckBox` of `TForm1` is checked.

I looked on Google, but that gave me nothing good on this sort of thing.

Any advice?

`TFORM1`

```
//...

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormOne::MyCheckBoxClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  FormTwo->Show();
}
```

`TFORM2`

```
//...

#include "Unit2.h"
#include "Unit1.h"

//...

int MSecond = 0, MyTime = 0;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TFormTwo::TFormTwo(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
  ProgressBar->Min = 0;
  ProgressBar->Max = 100;
  ProgressBar->Position = 0;
  Timer1->Enabled = true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  MyTime = GetTickCount();
  MSecond = 0;
  Timer1->Enabled = false;
  ProgressBar->Position = 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
  MSecond = GetTickCount( ) - MyTime;
  if (MSecond < 30000)
    ProgressBar->Position = double Trunc(double(MSecond) / 300);
  else
  {
    ProgressBar->Position = 100;
    Timer1->Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: BTW, **DO NOT** use the `OnCreate` event in C++.  It is a Delphi idiom that creates illegal behavior in C++.  Use the constructor instead.  In fact, all of the code that you currently have in `TFormTwo::FormCreate()` does not belong in this project to begin with, so get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not implement `TFormTwo` correctly for what you are attempting to accomplish.  It should look more like this instead:

```
class TFormTwo : class(TFormTwo)
{
__published:
    TProgressBar *ProgressBar;
    TTimer *Timer1;
    //...
    void __fastcall FormShow(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormHide(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action);
    void __fastcall Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender);
    //...
private:
    DWORD StartTime;
    //...
public:
    __fastcall TFormTwo(TComponent* Owner);
};
```

```
__fastcall TFormTwo::TFormTwo(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    // you should set these at design-time instead
    ProgressBar->Min = 0;
    ProgressBar->Max = 100;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    ProgressBar->Position = 0;
    StartTime = GetTickCount();
    Timer1->Enabled = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::FormHide(TObject *Sender)
{
    Timer1->Enabled = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    Timer1->Enabled = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TFormTwo::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
    DWORD MSecond = GetTickCount() - StartTime;
    if (MSecond < 30000)
        ProgressBar->Position = int((double(MSecond) / 30000.0) * 100.0);
    else
    {
        ProgressBar->Position = 100;
        Timer1->Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much Remy Lebeau. It works very well. Ouch, I forgot to ask 1 thing. If I wanna shutdown my computer automatically after `30 seconds` / `100% of ProgressBar` , where's the right place to put the `system("shutdown -s -f -t 0");` ?. I've tried to put it right after the `else {` statement, but I'm sorry, it doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: Don't use `system()` like that. Instead, use [`ExitWindowsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868.aspx), [`InitiateShutdown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872.aspx), [`InitiateSystemShutdown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873.aspx), or [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874.aspx). As for *where* to call it, you have the correct spot. You just have to make sure your app has adequate *permission* to shutdown the computer to begin with.